# Pandas to_excel named columns issue with dropna and reset_index

Tags: python, pandas

My original dataframe is 80x23. All columns after 7 are empty so I would like to remove them before writing the dataframe to Excel. The dataframe also does not have column names so I would like to add the 7 column names while writing to Excel. However the following code results in an error where it appears that the dropna and reset_index are not working (the df reverts back to 23 columns!)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = result)
print('STEP 1:' + str(len(df.columns)) + ',' + str(df.shape[0]))

nan_value = float("NaN")
df.replace("", nan_value, inplace = True)
df.dropna(how="all", axis=1, inplace = True)
print('STEP 2:' + str(len(df.columns)) + ',' + str(df.shape[0]))

dfT = df.T
print('STEP 3:' + str(len(dfT.columns)) + ',' + str(dfT.shape[0]))
 
# These lines below are causing an error (as soon as uncommented)
#dfT.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
#dfT.to_excel(filename, index = False, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'E', 'G'])
```

The results of print lines with those 2 lines commented are

```
STEP 1:80,7
STEP 2:80,7
STEP 3:7,80
```

The error when the 2 lines are uncommented:

```
STEP 1:80,23
STEP 2:80,23
STEP 3:23,80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\process_stdf_coa.py", line 12, in <module>
    STDF_dict = functions.parse_STDF()
  File "C:\Projects\ADAS\HFL110_G6R2\Python Database\functions.py", line 97, in parse_STDF
    common_dict = compare_dicts(df_dict, df2_dict, 'FALSE', 'TRUE')
  File "C:\Projects\ADAS\HFL110_G6R2\Python Database\functions.py", line 37, in compare_dicts
    dfT.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5154, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 66, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 564, in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 227, in set_axis
    f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 23 elements, new values have 7 elements
```

So somehow the deleted columns are back when I try to rename the columns for to_excel.

How can I get this to work?

-- Update
So this is happening only when the df is built from a dictionary but not when df is read from Excel with the same matrix.
So

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary) fails
df = pd.read_excel(xlsfile,index=0,na_values=['NA']) works
```

The dictionary and xlsfile have the same 80x23 elements and column 0 in the excel are the keys of the dictionary.

So perhaps the dictionary carries additional information that needs to be got rid of earlier? Any ideas on this?

Comment: There isn't any way that uncommenting those lines can cause the shape of the dataframe to be different in step 1. You need to [edit] your question with a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Why do you transpose your dataframe? The problem occurs when you try to rename columns because in `dfT`, columns are now your index.

```
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

Error is here:

```
>>> dfT.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
...
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 23 elements, new values have 7 elements
```

Comment: That did not work either. And without transposing, I cannot get the Excel output to match the df row/columns (which is strange). If I write the 80x7 df directly to Excel, I get 7 rows and 80 columns in the output which is not correct. If I write the transposed 7x80 dfT to Excel, I get the correct 80 rows and 7 columns in the output. That is why I need the transpose.

Comment: Applying it to df, I get: ValueError:Length mismatch: Expected axis has 80 elements, new values have 7 elements

Comment: In this case, try `dfT.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']` but I won't understand if it worked.